# How to select an element without selecting its pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a pure CSS-based hamburger menu toggle. This is the HTML, and CSS, that I'm using:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  gap: 3rem;
}

.menu-toggle-label span,
.menu-toggle-label span::before,
.menu-toggle-label span::after{
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black; 
  display: block;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu-toggle-label span::before,
.menu-toggle-label span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.menu-toggle-label span::before {
  transform: translateY(-16px);
}

.menu-toggle-label span::after {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}

.menu-toggle:checked~.menu-toggle-label>span {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-toggle:checked~.menu-toggle-label>span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.menu-toggle:checked~.menu-toggle-label>span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle">
<nav></nav>
<label class="menu-toggle-label" for="menu-toggle">
<span></span>
</label>
```

When checkbox gets checked, I want to hide the main span element and transform its pseudo-element into a cross.

However, the style below selects its pseudo-elements instead of selecting only the main span element. So all of them get hidden.

```css
.menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-toggle-label > span {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a snippet so that it can be demonstrated in your question; could please update it to show the problem you describe?

Comment: I have updated the snippet as per the question. Also Thanks to @QueryKiller I found the solution instead of opacity if I change background-color to transparent, it only affect the main span element. But I do not understand why opacity affects both main and pseudo elements but background-color only affects the main element?

Answer (score 0):

change the background-color of the main span to match the background of its container when checked.

```
.menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-toggle-label > span {
  background-color: transparent; /* or whatever the container's background color is */
}
.menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-toggle-label > span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-toggle-label > span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Hopefully this should do the trick for you.

Comment: adding opacity : 0 hides both pseudo elements.

Comment: Try changing the background-color of the main span to match the background of its container when checked, making it "hidden" I updated my css in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, changing the background color has fixed the issue. But why background-color property  affected only the main span but opacity affected both main and pseudo element?

Comment: opacity affects an element and all its content, including pseudo-elements. background-color doesn't inherit, so it only affects what you directly apply it to

I hope my answer helped solve your issue =)

Comment: Make the background color transparent rather than build in the background color just in case it is changed in future.

Comment: Thanks for the help @QueryKiller and thanks for the suggestion @A Haworth

Comment: No problem! If you liked my answer could you mark it as accepted? that would be awesome